# Autofac null service resolve exception

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, autofac

I have a 3 project in my solution:
Portable Library (for ios, android and winphones), library project(for windows phone) and windows phone test project. My library project got reference to portable library project, and my windows phone test project got reference to portable and winphone library project. In my portable library project I got some service interface which I implement in library winphone project. In my portable project I want have some class that have fields with service that I implement in windows phone library and use this class in windows phone test project. To do this i try use Autofac library, to register types in my windows phone library( to do this I made class with static ctor) and try to resolve service in my portable library class which I register in my windows phone library, but I got null exception and I don't know how to fix that, and it is possible to do things which I actually trying to do ?

My class from portable library project, after call Resolve method I go exception.

```
    public IDeviceInformation DeviceInformation { get; }

    public Logger()
    {
        DeviceInformation = AutofacContainer.Instance.Resolve<IDeviceInformation>();
    }
```

Class from library project

```
public class AutoFacRegister
{

    static AutoFacRegister()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<WindowsDeviceInformation>()
            .As<IDeviceInformation>();
        AutofacContainer.Instance = builder.Build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend against using a `static` constructor to create your container. I suspect that the constructor is never called since the `AutoFacRegister` class is not used anywhere and therefore `AutofacContainer.Instance` will always be null.

I would suggest to use [modules](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/configuration/modules.html) to achieve your goal.